# Python - Finding Difference Between Two Mouse Positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to find the differences between two mouse positions. Although, I cant figure it out, I am a beginner and was wondering if anyone can help me out.

I am trying to make a program that prints out how far you've moved your mouse in x amount of time. This is the only part I cant figure out.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

time.sleep(1)
x = (pyautogui.position())

time.sleep(1)
y = (pyautogui.position())

p = x - y
print(p)
```

I expected it to print out the difference but it gives me an error.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Point' and 'Point'
```

Comment: The position of a mouse is a two-dimensional coordinate, not just a number. You have to calculate distance between two two-dimensional coordinates. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346103/distance-between-two-points

Comment: You are getting that error because subtraction cannot be applied on Object of type `Point`. Pythagorean theorem helps a lot if you are planning to find distance between two mouse position. Since, on screen mouse will always be in a 2D plain, so there will be two coordinates for each mouse pointer, x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html). You have to store the coordinates in two objects if you want to get separate coordinates:

```
x, y = pyautogui.position()
```

Now you can get the distance vector with simple arithmetics:

```
time.sleep(1)
x0, y0 = (pyautogui.position())

time.sleep(1)
x1, y1 = (pyautogui.position())

Distance_X = x1 - x0
Distance_Y = y1 - y0
```

Otherwise, you have to use the `x` or `y` member of the `Point` object.

```
time.sleep(1)
P0 = (pyautogui.position())

time.sleep(1)
P1 = (pyautogui.position())

Distanxe_X = P1.x - P0.x
Distance_Y = P1.y - P0.y
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pyautogui` returns a `Point` which is a 2-D coordinate of the form `(x,y)`

You need to use the [Distance Formula](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/basic-geo/basic-geometry-pythagorean-theorem/pythagorean-theorem-distance/a/distance-formula) to compute the Distance between any two points

Working example below

```
import time
import pyautogui
import math

time.sleep(1)
x = (pyautogui.position())

time.sleep(1)
y = (pyautogui.position())

dist = math.sqrt((y.x - x.x)**2 + (y.y - x.y)**2)

print(round(dist, 2))
```

Also, `pyautogui` is not a part of the `tkinter` module in Python 3. So I have installed and imported it separately.